# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::make() in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel-4, response

I am using Laravel 4.2. While using `make` method of `Response` class i am getting undefined method error.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $contents = "Hello";
    $response = Response::make($contents, 200);
    return $response;
});
```

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: at the top of your routes add this: `use Illuminate\Http\Response;`

Comment: @aldrin27 i already did, but still getting error

Answer (score 20):

The error is absolutely correct.. `make` doesn't exist in the `Http` class, it exists as an accessor method off of the `Facade` class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
```

If you (for some reason) need both, just alias it.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response as FacadeResponse;
```

Then you can just do `$response = FacadeResponse::make($content, 200);`

[Have a gander at the docs](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.html) for more information.

Comment: But how then laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies) uses Response::make() method ??

Comment: @Cody What do you mean? It uses `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response`. It doesn't use the the `Http` class. [Look here at the docs for the Http class](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Http/Response.html). Also, why the downvote? There's noithing incorrecft about my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simple thing I did for this problem

```
return \Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

I put forward slash ( \ ) before Response.